# Flutter List + Pull to load more data is not waiting for data to load before it finishes causing the list / scrolling to become unstable

Tags: dart, flutter

If you make a new Flutter project and include the dependencies and then replace your main.dart file you should be where I am on this question.

---

I left the original load: with Future.delayed but it doesn't seem to matter.  I know partially what my problem is but am unable to come up with a better solution.

1) I don't seem to be using my snapshot.data and instead I am just making a empty List with `str` and then i just addAll into it and use that.  So i'd love to not do that, i originally was using snapshot.data but ran into problems when I tried to "pull to load more data" which happens after you scroll to the bottom of the list.

**The problem** with my current method of doing this is that if you pull to load more users and then try to pull again before the users have loaded, The app breaks and doesn't wait for the data to properly load.  I believe that I need to be doing that all in the `load:` of this library `easy_refresh`... but I am not sure how to rewrite my code to accomplish that.

How can I get my data to load with snapshot.data and then when I pull to refresh, I append 100 more users to that list but the UI waits for the list to update before it finishes the load.   Would I be better off just putting a Blocking UI element and after the str list updates? and when new users are loaded I unblock the UI?  which sorta feels hackish and not the correct way to solve this.  The plugin itself should be able to do the loading and when its ready it stops the spinner under the list and says "finished".

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
flutter:
  sdk: flutter

flutter_easyrefresh: ^1.2.7
http: ^0.12.0+2
```

**main.dart**

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'dart:convert';
  import 'package:flutter_easyrefresh/easy_refresh.dart';
  import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white
        ),
        home: DuelLeaderBoards(),
      );
    }
  }


  class DuelLeaderBoards extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _DuelLeaderBoardsState createState() => _DuelLeaderBoardsState();
  }

  class _DuelLeaderBoardsState extends State<DuelLeaderBoards> {
    List<Entry> str = [];
    GlobalKey<EasyRefreshState> _easyRefreshKey = new GlobalKey<EasyRefreshState>();
    GlobalKey<RefreshHeaderState> _headerKey = new GlobalKey<RefreshHeaderState>();
    GlobalKey<RefreshHeaderState> _connectorHeaderKey = new GlobalKey<RefreshHeaderState>();
    GlobalKey<RefreshFooterState> _footerKey = new GlobalKey<RefreshFooterState>();
    GlobalKey<RefreshFooterState> _connectorFooterKey = new GlobalKey<RefreshFooterState>();

    Future<LeaderBoards> getLeaderBoards(start) async {
      String apiURL = 'https://stats.quake.com/api/v2/Leaderboard?from=$start&board=duel&season=current';

      final response = await http.get(apiURL);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseBody = leaderBoardsFromJson(response.body);
        return responseBody;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
      }
    }

    void updateLeaderBoardList(e) async {
      setState(() {
        str.addAll(e.entries);
      });
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      getLeaderBoards(0).then((onValue) => str = onValue.entries );
      super.initState();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      Widget header = ClassicsHeader(
        key: _headerKey,
        refreshText: "pullToRefresh",
        refreshReadyText: "releaseToRefresh",
        refreshingText: "refreshing...",
        refreshedText: "refreshed",
        moreInfo: "updateAt",
        bgColor: Colors.transparent,
        textColor: Colors.white,
      );
      Widget footer = ClassicsFooter(
        key: _footerKey,
        loadHeight: 50.0,
        loadText: "pushToLoad",
        loadReadyText: "releaseToLoad",
        loadingText: "loading",
        loadedText: "loaded",
        noMoreText: "Finished",
        moreInfo: "updateAt",
        bgColor: Colors.transparent,
        textColor: Colors.white,
      );
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: getLeaderBoards(0),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<LeaderBoards> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            } else {
              return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Center(
                    child: new EasyRefresh(
                      key: _easyRefreshKey,
                      behavior: ScrollOverBehavior(),
                      refreshHeader: ConnectorHeader(
                        key: _connectorHeaderKey,
                        header: header,
                      ),
                      refreshFooter: ConnectorFooter(
                        key: _connectorFooterKey,
                        footer: footer,
                      ),
                      child: CustomScrollView(
                        semanticChildCount: str.length,
                        slivers: <Widget>[
                          SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(<Widget>[header]),
                          ),
                          SliverList(
                              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                    (context, index) {
                                      return new Container(
                                          height: 70.0,
                                          child: Card(
                                            child: new Text(
                                              '${index+1}: ${str[index].userName}',
                                              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                          ));
                                },
                                childCount: str.length,
                              )),
                          SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(<Widget>[footer]),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      onRefresh: () async {
                        await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
                          setState(() {});
                        });
                      },
                      loadMore: () async {
                        getLeaderBoards(str.length).then((onValue) => {
                        updateLeaderBoardList(onValue)
                        });
                      },
  //                    loadMore: () async {
  //                      await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
  //                        getLeaderBoards(str.length).then((onValue) => {
  //                              updateLeaderBoardList(onValue)
  //                        });
  //                      });
  //                    },
                    )
                );
              });
            }
          });
    }
  }



  LeaderBoards leaderBoardsFromJson(String str) {
    final jsonData = json.decode(str);
    return LeaderBoards.fromJson(jsonData);
  }

  String leaderBoardsToJson(LeaderBoards data) {
    final dyn = data.toJson();
    return json.encode(dyn);
  }

  class LeaderBoards {
    String boardType;
    List<Entry> entries;
    int totalEntries;

    LeaderBoards({
      this.boardType,
      this.entries,
      this.totalEntries,
    });

    factory LeaderBoards.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new LeaderBoards(
      boardType: json["boardType"] == null ? null : json["boardType"],
      entries: json["entries"] == null ? null : new List<Entry>.from(json["entries"].map((x) => Entry.fromJson(x))),
      totalEntries: json["totalEntries"] == null ? null : json["totalEntries"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "boardType": boardType == null ? null : boardType,
      "entries": entries == null ? null : new List<dynamic>.from(entries.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      "totalEntries": totalEntries == null ? null : totalEntries,
    };
  }

  class Entry {
    String userName;
    int eloRating;
    String profileIconId;
    String namePlateId;

    Entry({
      this.userName,
      this.eloRating,
      this.profileIconId,
      this.namePlateId,
    });

    factory Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Entry(
      userName: json["userName"] == null ? null : json["userName"],
      eloRating: json["eloRating"] == null ? null : json["eloRating"],
      profileIconId: json["profileIconId"] == null ? null : json["profileIconId"],
      namePlateId: json["namePlateId"] == null ? null : json["namePlateId"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
      "userName": userName == null ? null : userName,
      "eloRating": eloRating == null ? null : eloRating,
      "profileIconId": profileIconId == null ? null : profileIconId,
      "namePlateId": namePlateId == null ? null : namePlateId,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the [documentation of loadMore](https://github.com/xuelongqy/flutter_easyrefresh/blob/master/README_EN.md#2add-easyrefresh). Since it says that the body of the function assigned to `loadMore` should be `async`, you do not need to use `then`:

```
loadMore: () async {
     final result = await getLeaderBoards(str.length);
     updateLeaderboardList(result);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
loadMore: () async {
     await getLeaderBoards(str.length).then((onValue) => {
     updateLeaderboardList(onValue)
     });
},
```

but putting "await" my loader waits for the function to complete before it finishes the animation.

Comment: You either use async/await or the `then` function. You don't need to use both of them simultaneously.